# display the value of a loop count in inputdlg box?

Tags: matlab

apologies for the rather vague question, i've written a simple for statment, where players is a predetermined integer:

```
for k = 0:players;
    inputdlg('Enter the name of player (?): ');
end
```

i'd like to have the section (?) to be automatically populated as the statement counts through the player number.
can anyone suggest a way to do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` :

```
for k = 0:players
    st = sprintf('Enter the name of player %d',k);
    inputdlg(st);
end
```

Comment: say, for example, i wanted to convert these names into numbers, could i use something like: player_num %d = str2num(st %d); ?